# Accessing elements in a list property from a seperate class.

Tags: c#, list, properties

I have one class that is going to contain multiple lists that hold a variety of game objects. These lists will get populated by JSON scripts further in development.

Right now, I'm trying to access 1 element in 1 list. I have filled my class out as so:

```
public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public List<GameObject> primaryWeapons = new List<GameObject>();

    public List<GameObject> PrimaryWeapons
    {
        get { return primaryWeapons; }
    }

    public GameObject gameObj1, gameObj2;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        FillList();
    }

    public void FillList()
    {

        primaryWeapons.Add(gameObj1);
        primaryWeapons.Add(gameObj2);
    }
}
```

In my second class I'm trying to access one of the game objects I have placed in the list. This what I have so far:

```
ShopManager primary;
public GameObject temp;
public List<GameObject> tmpList;
void Awake()
{
    primary = new ShopManager();
    primary.FillList();

    tmpList= new List<GameObject>();
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < primary.PrimaryWeapons.Count; i++)
    {
        tmpList.Add(primary.PrimaryWeapons[i]);
    }
    Debug.Log(primary.PrimaryWeapons.Count);
}


public void SelectWeapon1()
{
    temp = primary.PrimaryWeapons.Where(obj => obj.gameObject.name == "DoorParts_1").SingleOrDefault();


}
```

}

In my list in the shop manager class I am manually setting the objects myself, so I know the names of them. However, whilst I can get a count returning correctly, I am unable to access this named object.

When I run the code I get a null reference pointing to the following line:

```
 temp = primary.PrimaryWeapons.Where(obj => obj.gameObject.name == "DoorParts_1").SingleOrDefault();
```

Additonally I even created another list with the idea of passing the contents from my List property in the `ShopManager` class to this temp one. However, this lists populates with 2 empty positions.

I'm still not 100% on using properties like this. Espcially with lists. Could someone please tell me what it is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your objects in ShopManager.
Replace this:

```
public GameObject gameObj1, gameObj2;
```

With this:

```
public GameObject gameObj1 = new GameObject(), gameObj2 = new GameObject();
```

Comment: Just tried that but I get the following error 'UnityException: You are not allowed to call this function when declaring a variable.' so I moved it into the FillList() method but it didn't do anything.

Comment: First of all your duplicate your FillList func(You call it in the contractor and in your Awake func. So call it only one. and share your updated code

Answer (score 0):

Check `GameObject` initialization. Especially `gameObject` field.

`primary.PrimaryWeapons.Where(obj => obj.gameObject.name == "DoorParts_1").SingleOrDefault();` can fail with null reference in just few conditions:

- `primary` is null
- `primary.PrimaryWeapons` is null
- `obj.gameObject` is null

The first two look covered in your code. So, check how `GameObject.gameObject` field is initialized.